# /usr/bin/ld: warning: libinference_engine.so, needed by /opt/intel/computer_vision_sdk_2018.2.319/opencv/lib/libopencv_dnn.so.3.4.2, not found

Tags: python, compiling, intel, docker, cmake

I'm following the setup guide for OpenVino, but am unable to get the samples running.

The squeezenet and security barrier demos run fine.

The error that I am getting is:

```
  /usr/bin/ld: warning: libinference_engine.so, needed by /opt/intel/computer_vision_sdk_2018.2.319/opencv/lib/libopencv_dnn.so.3.4.2, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
```

the location of libinference_engine.so is included:

```
/opt/intel/computer_vision_sdk_2018.2.319/deployment_tools/inference_engine/lib/ubuntu_16.04/intel64
```

When I `ls` the above location, libinference_engine.so is present.

Where Is the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

Can you please advise what to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please start your application like this:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/intel/computer_vision_sdk_2018.2.319/deployment_tools/inference_engine/lib/ubuntu_16.04/intel64 your_application_here
```